# iOS 5 Problems converting an NSDictionary to an NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios5, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, ipod

I am creating an IPOD App and I have an NSDictionary that I have created from a JSON feed. I am trying to convert this to an NSMutableArray. I know I need to loop through the dictionary and write the keys and values to the array but I am having problems with the code. This is what to accomplish this.

////   Get the JSON data from the website
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

```
////// convert the dictionary to an NSMutableArray
// create an empty array of size equal to the number of json records
NSMutableArray *users = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];                           
//  Begin filling the array
NSInteger dCount = [json count];

for(int i=0; i <  dCount; i++)
{
    User *user = [[User alloc] init];
    user.emailAddress = [json objectForKey: @"emailAddress"];
    user.password = [json objectForKey: @"password"];
    user.password = [json objectForKey: @"password"];
    [users addObject:user];
    NSLog(@"This is record: %@", i);
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay may not be the most elegant solution but with a lot of help this is what I came up with:

////////////////  Build the array of users on the service
    dispatch_queue_t bgQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(bgQueue, ^{

```
////// Building users list
//Get the data from the webserver 
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://msis-discussion-forum.appspot.com/users"]];

NSLog(@"Beginning to build array");
////   Get the JSON data from the website
NSError* error;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"This is my JSON data %@", json);
usersArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSArray *userJSONObjects = [json objectForKey:@"users"];
for (User *tempUser in userJSONObjects)
{
    User *user = [[User alloc] init];
    user.displayName = [tempUser valueForKey:@"displayName"];
    NSLog(@"%@",user.displayName);
    user.emailAddress = [tempUser valueForKey:@"emailAddress"];
    NSLog(@"%@",user.emailAddress);
    user.password = [tempUser valueForKey: @"password"];
    NSLog(@"%@",user.password);
    [usersArray addObject:user];
} 
 });
```

Hope it helps.